# Apply gradient to a tensor in a sparse way in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a very large tensor `L` (millions of elements), from which I gather a relatively small subtensor `S` (maybe a thousand of elements).

I then apply my model to `S`, compute loss, and backpropagate to `S` and to `L` with the intent to only update selected elements in `L`. Problem is PyTorch makes `L`'s gradient to be a continuous tensor, so it basically doubles `L`'s memory usage.

Is there an easy way to compute and apply gradient to `L` without doubling memory usage?

Sample code to illustrate the problem:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn.parameter import Parameter

net = nn.Sequential(
  nn.Linear(1, 64),
  nn.ReLU(),
  nn.Linear(64,64),
  nn.ReLU(),
  nn.Linear(64, 1))

L = Parameter(torch.zeros([1024*1024*256], dtype=torch.float32))
L.data.uniform_(-1, 1)

indices = torch.randint(high=256*1024*1024, size=[1024])
S = torch.unsqueeze(L[indices], dim=1)

out = net(S)

loss = out.sum()

loss.backward()

print(loss)
g = L.grad
print(g.shape)  # this is huge!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need `requires_grad` on `L` as gradients will be computed and applied manually. Instead, set it on `S`. That will stop backpropagation at `S`.

Then, you can update the values of `L` using `S.grad` and your preferred optimization. Something along these lines

```
L = torch.zeros([1024*1024*256], dtype=torch.float32)

...

S = torch.unsqueeze(L[indices], dim=1)
S.requires_grad_()

out = net(S)

loss = torch.abs(out).sum()

loss.backward()

with torch.no_grad():   
  L[indices] -= learning_rate * torch.squeeze(S.grad)
  S.grad.zero_()
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the detach part? The training loop would start at `indices = `. Would I need to call `S.detach()`? `L.detach()`?

Comment: I figured it out, do you mind if I edit your answer with a full code sample?

Comment: Sure, go for it

Comment: Pretty sure you can also just do `L = torch.zeros([1024*1024*256], dtype=torch.float32,requires_grad = False)`
`

Comment: actually, you need to explicitly set `requires_grad` to `True` on `S`, and don't need to detach anything. I edited your answer, feel free to edit further.